# Django URL resolution doesn't work when running Apache/WSGI

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

When I run my application using Djangos built-in server, everything works ok. But when I try to run via Apache and WSGI the URL is no longer recognized but the it is in the urls.py file.

The error page I get is this:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/project/app/live/
Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$
    ^app/live/
The current URL, app/live/, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

As you can see, the URL (app/live/) is right there in the URL patterns from the top-level urls.py file. There are also no errors in the Apache errors.log file.

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', 
                        { 'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT }),
                       (r'^app/live/', include('project.app.urls', app_name='live')),
                       )
```

My WSGI file:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/../..')

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.settings"

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And finally my Apache configuration:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess   project processes=2 maximum-requests=500 threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup    project
WSGIScriptReloading On

WSGIScriptAlias /project /home/user/project/apache/project.wsgi
```

**EDIT:**

After putting in some debugging output in RegexURLResolver, I saw that it tries to resolve both `app/live/` and `project/app/live/`.

So I changed my urls.py file to this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^app/live/', include('project.app.urls', app_name='live')),
                       (r'^project/app/live/', include('project.app.urls', app_name='live')),
                       )
```

Works now.

Comment: 2) Because otherwise it doesn't find the settings module. `ImportError: Could not import settings 'project.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named project.settings`. Maybe my whole project/app setup is misconfigured?

Comment: Oh, I see, you have an extra "apache" subdirectory for the WSGI file. nvm

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your config. Do you have the latest mod_wsgi/Django versions? You could also try to print-debug `RegexURLResolver.resolve`.

Answer (score 2):

*REMOVING* the trailing slash on `WSGIScriptAlias /django` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Add the trailing slash to your URL path prefix in your Apache configuration:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /project/ /home/user/project/apache/project.wsgi
```

Comment: In my experience, adding a slash to WSGIScriptAlias's URL path rather breaks the whole application (404 errors, using Apache 2 on Debian). Any reason (or reference) why you say this should work?

Comment: Adding a trailing slash give me the following error in Apaches error.log: `Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /home/user/project/apache/project.wsgiapp`.

Comment: That's exactly the problem I meant. mod_wsgi appends the alias-relative URL to the WSGI filename iff the alias ends with a slash (doesn't make any sense, but that's how it is). So this doesn't solve OP's problem.

Comment: AndiDog is correct. A trailing slash would usually only be used on WSGIScriptAlias if the final argument refers to a directory and NOT a WSGI script file. In the case of final argument being a directory, the directory path should also have a trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1, edit your apache configs:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/project/apache/project.wsgi
```

Solution 2, edit your urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   (r'^/project/media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', 
                    { 'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT }),
                   (r'^/project/app/live/', include('project.app.urls', app_name='live')),
                   )
```

Also, you probably do not want to serve your static content through django if you are using apache:

```
Alias /media /path/to/media/root
<Location /media>
SetHandle None
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hate to bring an old thread to life but, I fixed this issue by making sure my apache2 config wrapped the python path in quotes like:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/django_project/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath "/home/user:/home/user/.virtualenvs/djangodev/lib/python3.4/site-packages"
```

I'm using Django 1.9, python3.4, and a virtualenv while following [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

**UPDATE:** Scratch that, I'm a maroon and didn't read well enough to see I need to use mod_wsgi in daemon mode to avoid the need to restart apache every time I make changes.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path="/home/user:/home/user/.virtualenvs/djangodev/lib/python3.4/site-packages"
WSGIProcessGroup example.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/django_project/wsgi.py process-group=example.com
```